# Static Website On Premise Deployment on a ISS server Using Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have static website(Just some hmtl,css and javascript along with devextreme components) that i've stored inside a azure git repository. I also have a server that i use for hosting my personal projects. I want to deploy two branches of my code(master and test) as seperate sites to this server. My server is a windows machine, as such, i am using IIS.  I want my sites to be constantly up to date with my changes.
While i think i understand how to deploy to On-Premise servers  using pipelines and deployment groups thanks to some guides, almost all of them uses .net core for their example codebase. So right now i am kinda stuck. Is there a way for me to achieve what i want? Side note : I prefer not to deal with YAML, but i can i have to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a self-hosted agent which has network access to your server, and write a YAML pipeline to copy your repo's files to your server. Should be a very short YAML script, maybe just a "copy files" task.